Finding shortest path for grid with rotating cells
I stumbled upon a problem like this:
Let's say you have some number of grids. Each grid have the same dimension of rows and columns. Each cell in grid can be represented as either L or _ . Also take in consideration that:

Each cell L can be rotated 3 times (by 90 degrees)
Each cell _ can be rotated once (by 90 degrees)
Grid representation starts at (0,0) from top left and ends at (rows-1, columns-1) bottom right.

Example
2 grids of dimension 3x3.
Grid 1:
start ->|L|_|L|
        |L|_|L|
        |_|_|L|<- finish

Grid 2:
start ->|L|_|L|
        |L|_|L|
        |_|L|L|<- finish

Solution
Grid 1:
start ->|2|x|x|
        |0|0|2|
        |x|x|0|<- finish

Grid 2:
start ->|2|x|x|
        |0|0|2|
        |x|x|0|<- finish

Explanation
Let's take Grid 1 on the table.
Remember that the grid starts from top left (0,0) to bottom right (2,2)

The cell at (0,0) [2] has to be rotated 2 times because it will connect to the start with it's tip.
Next cell (0,1) [0] does not need to be rotated because it connects to the cell at (0,0)
Next cell (1,1) [0] does not need to be rotated because it connects to the cell at (0,1)
The cell at (2,1) [2] has to be rotated 2 times to connect with its tip to the cell at (1,1)
The cell at (2,2) does need to be rotated because it already connects to the cell at (2,1) with it's tip and is connected to the finish with other tip

Problem
I'm trying to figure out an algorithm but can't quite get there, I've tried implementing BFS but to no avail (the rotations makes it surprisingly hard). The algorithm should find how many rotations each cell requires for each grid to connect start to finish. Grids are randomly filled with cells of random 90 degree rotation. The filling algorithm makes sure there is always a path from start to finish. Any suggestions how should I approach this?
Edit

"connect to the start with it's tip" visually means this:

"rotation" means each cell can be rotated clockwise by 90 degrees


Let us continue this discussion in chat.

The usual way to solve this kind of problem is to extend your grids into a third dimension.  Each new layer has the cells in the grid rotated by one more 'rotation'.  The links between adjacent cells in one layer have a cost of 1 but you can move between the layers at zero cost.
Now you can use the Dijkstra algorithm to find the shortest path from start to finish.  When the path is found, using different layers, the layers can be collapsed, so the path is in 2D but the cells have been 'rotated' as they were in the 3D layer.
Your diagram, showing which sides of a cell are connected to adjacent cells, is much improved. Here is how I understand it.



cell
rotations
connected sides




L
0
t,r


L
1
r,b


L
2
b,l


L
3
l,t


I
0
l,r


I
1
t,b



With this table you should be able to create the 3D extensions of your grids, generate the graph from them and apply Dijsktra.
Let's start with the first grid in your example.  Here are the internal cell connections for the 3D extended grid ( 'rl' means the right and left cell sides are connected by n unrotated '_' cell type )

You can find the code that produces this at https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79193582
The next step is to write down the graph edges. This is straightforward, though tedious.
A vertex is created for each cell side. The vertices are labelled like this 0_1_2_t which is the top side of the cell at row 0, col 1, layer 2.
There are 3 sorts of connections. The connections between sides of the same cell ( e,g the left and right sides of an unrotated '-' cell. These connections are 'free'. The connections between adjacent cells in the same layer if their connected side are connected internally. These connections cost 1 unit. The connections between layers. Every node is connected to the identical node in the layer above and below with zero cost.
As you can see, that is a lot of connections! So I wrote some code to do the tedious work. https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79193582/blob/26f98b046ad71fddac3dd7fbafe2cd0e3e29e3fb/src/main.cpp#L143-L236
Here is the edge list for your first grid
0_0_3_l 0_0_3_t 0
0_2_3_l 0_2_3_t 0
1_0_3_l 1_0_3_t 0
1_2_3_l 1_2_3_t 0
2_2_3_l 2_2_3_t 0
0_0_2_b 0_0_2_l 0
0_2_2_b 0_2_2_l 0
1_0_2_b 1_0_2_l 0
1_2_2_b 1_2_2_l 0
2_2_2_b 2_2_2_l 0
0_0_1_r 0_0_1_b 0
0_1_1_t 0_1_1_b 0
0_2_1_r 0_2_1_b 0
1_0_1_r 1_0_1_b 0
1_1_1_t 1_1_1_b 0
1_2_1_r 1_2_1_b 0
2_0_1_t 2_0_1_b 0
2_1_1_t 2_1_1_b 0
2_2_1_r 2_2_1_b 0
0_0_0_t 0_0_0_r 0
0_1_0_l 0_1_0_r 0
0_2_0_t 0_2_0_r 0
1_0_0_t 1_0_0_r 0
1_1_0_l 1_1_0_r 0
1_2_0_t 1_2_0_r 0
2_0_0_l 2_0_0_r 0
2_1_0_l 2_1_0_r 0
2_2_0_t 2_2_0_r 0
0_1_1_b 1_1_1_t 1
1_0_1_b 2_0_1_t 1
1_1_1_b 2_1_1_t 1
0_0_0_r 0_1_0_l 1
1_0_0_r 1_1_0_l 1
2_0_0_r 2_1_0_l 1
0_0_3_t 0_0_2_t 0
0_0_3_r 0_0_2_r 0
0_0_3_b 0_0_2_b 0
0_0_3_l 0_0_2_l 0
0_1_3_t 0_1_2_t 0
0_1_3_r 0_1_2_r 0
0_1_3_b 0_1_2_b 0
0_1_3_l 0_1_2_l 0
0_2_3_t 0_2_2_t 0
0_2_3_r 0_2_2_r 0
0_2_3_b 0_2_2_b 0
0_2_3_l 0_2_2_l 0
1_0_3_t 1_0_2_t 0
1_0_3_r 1_0_2_r 0
1_0_3_b 1_0_2_b 0
1_0_3_l 1_0_2_l 0
1_1_3_t 1_1_2_t 0
1_1_3_r 1_1_2_r 0
1_1_3_b 1_1_2_b 0
1_1_3_l 1_1_2_l 0
1_2_3_t 1_2_2_t 0
1_2_3_r 1_2_2_r 0
1_2_3_b 1_2_2_b 0
1_2_3_l 1_2_2_l 0
2_0_3_t 2_0_2_t 0
2_0_3_r 2_0_2_r 0
2_0_3_b 2_0_2_b 0
2_0_3_l 2_0_2_l 0
2_1_3_t 2_1_2_t 0
2_1_3_r 2_1_2_r 0
2_1_3_b 2_1_2_b 0
2_1_3_l 2_1_2_l 0
2_2_3_t 2_2_2_t 0
2_2_3_r 2_2_2_r 0
2_2_3_b 2_2_2_b 0
2_2_3_l 2_2_2_l 0
0_0_2_t 0_0_1_t 0
0_0_2_r 0_0_1_r 0
0_0_2_b 0_0_1_b 0
0_0_2_l 0_0_1_l 0
0_1_2_t 0_1_1_t 0
0_1_2_r 0_1_1_r 0
0_1_2_b 0_1_1_b 0
0_1_2_l 0_1_1_l 0
0_2_2_t 0_2_1_t 0
0_2_2_r 0_2_1_r 0
0_2_2_b 0_2_1_b 0
0_2_2_l 0_2_1_l 0
1_0_2_t 1_0_1_t 0
1_0_2_r 1_0_1_r 0
1_0_2_b 1_0_1_b 0
1_0_2_l 1_0_1_l 0
1_1_2_t 1_1_1_t 0
1_1_2_r 1_1_1_r 0
1_1_2_b 1_1_1_b 0
1_1_2_l 1_1_1_l 0
1_2_2_t 1_2_1_t 0
1_2_2_r 1_2_1_r 0
1_2_2_b 1_2_1_b 0
1_2_2_l 1_2_1_l 0
2_0_2_t 2_0_1_t 0
2_0_2_r 2_0_1_r 0
2_0_2_b 2_0_1_b 0
2_0_2_l 2_0_1_l 0
2_1_2_t 2_1_1_t 0
2_1_2_r 2_1_1_r 0
2_1_2_b 2_1_1_b 0
2_1_2_l 2_1_1_l 0
2_2_2_t 2_2_1_t 0
2_2_2_r 2_2_1_r 0
2_2_2_b 2_2_1_b 0
2_2_2_l 2_2_1_l 0
0_0_1_t 0_0_0_t 0
0_0_1_r 0_0_0_r 0
0_0_1_b 0_0_0_b 0
0_0_1_l 0_0_0_l 0
0_1_1_t 0_1_0_t 0
0_1_1_r 0_1_0_r 0
0_1_1_b 0_1_0_b 0
0_1_1_l 0_1_0_l 0
0_2_1_t 0_2_0_t 0
0_2_1_r 0_2_0_r 0
0_2_1_b 0_2_0_b 0
0_2_1_l 0_2_0_l 0
1_0_1_t 1_0_0_t 0
1_0_1_r 1_0_0_r 0
1_0_1_b 1_0_0_b 0
1_0_1_l 1_0_0_l 0
1_1_1_t 1_1_0_t 0
1_1_1_r 1_1_0_r 0
1_1_1_b 1_1_0_b 0
1_1_1_l 1_1_0_l 0
1_2_1_t 1_2_0_t 0
1_2_1_r 1_2_0_r 0
1_2_1_b 1_2_0_b 0
1_2_1_l 1_2_0_l 0
2_0_1_t 2_0_0_t 0
2_0_1_r 2_0_0_r 0
2_0_1_b 2_0_0_b 0
2_0_1_l 2_0_0_l 0
2_1_1_t 2_1_0_t 0
2_1_1_r 2_1_0_r 0
2_1_1_b 2_1_0_b 0
2_1_1_l 2_1_0_l 0
2_2_1_t 2_2_0_t 0
2_2_1_r 2_2_0_r 0
2_2_1_b 2_2_0_b 0
2_2_1_l 2_2_0_l 0

The next step is to load this into your favorite graph theory library and apply the Dijkstra algorithm.
This will provide the shortest path through the extended 3D grid.  The final step is to collapse the path back down to two dimension, keeping track of the cell rotations required.  This can be done by picking out the path hops that move from one side to another of the same cell - the layer where this happens gives the required rotation.
Here are the results from the code in https://github.com/JamesBremner/so79193582 for your two example grids.



I failed to mention that the solution is always available (gonna add it to my question later on). In your diagram the bottom right cell should be cornered, not straight so path can be found: top right rotate 2 times and then bottom right rotated enough times so it connects to the finish and top right cell.

Im sorry for the confusion, yes I meant "L". This problem confuses me a lot and I'm making these mistakes, thabk you for your patience.

"the solution is always available"  I cannot imagine that it is possible to guarantee that!
